With my circuit breaker open I have found 0.67 VAC between my light switch common wire to ground, is this acceptable?
I have opened the circuit breaker at my box to diagnose why my outside light is not working. I verified that there is no VAC at the switch and I have disconnected the light switch from the circuit to run continuity test. I have checked continuity and verified it show OL, and the switch is bad.
This is the second light switch that has gone bad in this circuit since I installed a new outside light (8 months ago) so I was testing the "C" wire to (GRN) ground wire and find 0.67 VAC.
Is this causing the switches to go bad?

Location will be nice.  Common/com on a switch is more UK/Europe thing.  Type of switch will be nice also.  A single/two way simple switch or a smart switch.  Usually .67v might be phantom voltage picked up from another close live wire.

@BrentRodeck please do not write information in comments ... edit the question instead

You seem to be asking two different questions. Yes, an induced voltage of a few volts is common, normal, and harmless; there's almost no amperage behind it so when there's an actual load it vanishes. No, the induced voltage is not related to your switches going bad.
